# Strange behavior of uglifyed javascript code with string comparison

Tags: javascript

I created a jsfiddle here for a strange case : http://jsfiddle.net/YGcDR/

The idea is that an equality comparison function (probably not optimized) is causing a bug in the select2 library, when optimized with uglifyjs. (The bug is pretty hard to diagnose, all we know is that the patch associated to https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/840 fixes it, and the only thing the patche changes is the comparison code. So I'm really trying to form an hypothesis here !)

A patched version of the same function seems to behave properly, both in optimized and unoptimized case.

The 'meat' of the code is comparision done like this :

```
if (a.constructor === String) return a === b + "";
if (b.constructor === String) return b === a + "";
```

vs

```
if (a.constructor === String) return a + "" === b + "";
if (b.constructor === String) return b + "" === a + "";
```

The generated code is slightly different in both case :

```
n.constructor===String?n===t+"":t.constructor===String?t===n+"":!1
```

vs

```
n.constructor===String?n+""==t+"":t.constructor===String?t+""==n+"":!1}
```

The problem is, I can not think of any set of entries for a and b that could cause the difference. At first I though it could be a difference between `var a = "Foo" and var b = new String("Foo")`, but this does not seem to be the case. Anyone seeing why this could fail ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it browser-specific?  All functions behaving the same for me (Chrome)

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "is causing a but"?

Comment: I meant "a bug", I don't know if the specifics of the bugs are relevant - and to be honest, I can't easily reproduce it. All I know is that the patches changes the behavior, but I really have no clue how :)

Comment: You know that's not how to test for strings? And why the hell do you need an `equal` function?

Comment: If you do `equal(new String, "")` instead of `equal("", new String)` in the fiddle there is a change from before to after, yet the minified code always yields the same as the unminified one.

Comment: @Bergi I would definitely not write this kind of code, it is buried inside a library (select2). I'm more interested into the different behavior (but the bug is so hard to reproduce that the patch might be completely unrelated, in the end...)